# Spark Java Encoders.bean fail to convert to a Scala defined class

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have Java code to convert a `JavaRDD` to `Dataset` and save it to HDFS:

```
Dataset<User> userDataset = sqlContext.createDataset(userRdd.rdd(), Encoders.bean(User.class));
userDataset.write.json("some_path");
```

`User` class is defined in Scala language:

```
case class User(val name: Name, val address: Seq[Address]) extends Serializable

case class Name(firstName: String, lastName: Option[String])

case class Address(address: String)
```

Code complies and runs successfully, file is saved to HDFS, while `User` class in the output file has empty schema:

```
val users = spark.read.json("some_path")
users.count // 100,000 which is same as "userRdd"
users.printSchema // users: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = []
```

Why `Encoders.bean` is not working in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Encoders.bean` does not support Scala case class, `Encoders.product` supports that. `Encoders.product` takes a `TypeTag` as parameter while initializing a `TypeTag` is not possible in Java. I created a Scala object to provide `TypeTag`:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object MyTypeTags {
  val UserTypeTag: TypeTag[User] = typeTag[User]
}
```

Then in Java code: `Dataset<User> userDataset = sqlContext.createDataset(userRdd.rdd(), Encoders.product(MyTypeTags.UserTypeTag()));`